# How to specify which image/icon will show in odoo marketplace image and which will in app icon?

Tags: image, icons, odoo, marketplace

I was uploading my first app to odoo marketplace but stopped because I am confused between icons and app images how to define and where to define welcome image and where to define app icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I remember :

- icon:   `static/description/icon.png`
- welcome image : `static/src/img/main_screenshot.png`

and(optional) you can add `static/description/index.html` to describe all The features in your App in a fancy way (screen shots,  demo,  videos,... etc.

And add main_screenshot to your manifest file:

```
       'images': [
          'static/src/img/main_screenshot.png'
       ],
```

You can go to any repository of any free App to learn this things